# Where to put the files when setting up endpoints for wordpress REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to set up some custom endpoints using the WordPress REST API. But I can't figure out where to put the files so it does not disappear when for example, updating plugins, themes or WordPress itself.

So I guess I can't place them in the Theme im currently using, or in the plugins/rest-api folder.

Anyone knows where to put the files?

Answer (score 1):

Consider setting up a child theme: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Or, write a simple plugin: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin